# Piping from serial port on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, usb, serial-port

I have a USB to RS232 adapter with which I'm connecting my MacBook Pro (OS X 10.9) to an EVK1100 board from Atmel. The program on the board outputs a lot of information on the serial port and I'd like to be able to inspect it. However, I'm struggling to find a program for that.

Plugging in the adapter makes two devices appear:

- `/dev/cu.usbserial-FTB3VVRF`
- `/dev/tty.usbserial-FTB3VVRF`

I can't straight-up `cat` the tty device because it needs a baud rate. I can specify a baud rate with `screen` but it won't let me pipe and it'll only display a single screen's worth of data.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found nothing, so I wrote a short program to do just that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <termios.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2 || argc > 3)
    {
        cerr << "usage: " << argv[0] << " device [bauds]" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    string device = argv[1];
    unsigned long bauds = 9600;
    if (argc == 3)
    {
        char* result;
        bauds = strtoul(argv[2], &result, 10);
        if (*result != '\0')
        {
            cerr << "usage: " << argv[0] << " device [bauds]" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }

    int fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_NDELAY | O_NOCTTY);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror((string("can't open ") + argv[1]).c_str());
        exit(errno);
    }

    struct termios config;
    if (tcgetattr(fd, &config) < 0)
    {
        perror("can't get serial attributes");
        exit(errno);
    }

    if (cfsetispeed(&config, bauds) < 0 || cfsetospeed(&config, bauds) < 0)
    {
        perror("can't set baud rate");
        exit(errno);
    }

    config.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | ICRNL | INLCR | PARMRK | INPCK | ISTRIP | IXON);
    config.c_oflag = 0;
    config.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | IEXTEN | ISIG);
    config.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB);
    config.c_cflag |= CS8;
    config.c_cc[VMIN]  = 1;
    config.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSAFLUSH, &config) < 0)
    {
        perror("can't set serial attributes");
        exit(errno);
    }

    char buffer[80];
    while (true)
    {
        size_t n = read(fd, buffer, sizeof buffer);
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, n);
    }

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I used to

```
(stty speed 115200 >/dev/null && cat) </dev/cu.usbserial-FTB3VVRF | tee serial.log
```

when I wanted to pipe from serial.

Comment: An additional way to make this better would be to put it in an alias/function, so you could perhaps do `serial <port> <rate>` to get a stdout feed. I'll ponder that...

Answer (score 1):

I found out [pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/index.html) has a nifty little tool called [miniterm](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/examples.html#miniterm) that works great.  I used it like this:

```
$ pip install pyserial
$ python -m serial.tools.miniterm /dev/cu.usbserial 9600
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. To install `pySerial` as a python module (so that in the second command, python can find the mentioned module `serial.tools.miniterm`), need to install `pySerial` as a module: `python -m pip install pyserial`

Comment: And of course the output can be redirected (e.g. to a file): `python -m serial.tools.miniterm /dev/cu.usbmodem1421 115200 > sensor_data.txt`. `/dev/cu.usbmodem1421` is my port name, you need to replace it with your own port. To find the port name with which your device is known, do a `ls /dev/` (pardon if this is too obvious, this is for newbies, incl. myself).

Answer (score 0):

[CoolTerm](http://freeware.the-meiers.org) is a Mac terminal app that should be able to connect to your serial device.

Otherwise here is a [list of Mac GUI terminal apps](http://pbxbook.com/other/mac-ser.html). And here is [a list of (command line) Mac terminal software](http://pbxbook.com/other/mac-tty.html).